# Atomic transactions in Entity Framework 4.1 Code First without stored procedures

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, transactions, ef-code-first, atomic

Is there a way to implement transactions in code first without having to write stored procedures?

I have some scenarios where multi-table entries need to be created with unique guids before a final table entry can be created. Is this something I can code using EF alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DbContext.SaveChanges()` method uses a transaction . So it is Atomic and you don't want to use stored procedures. The unitOfWork patter is implemented in EF itself to accomplish this.
But let's say you are using two DbContext instances to d your job , then you need to wrap your work with a transaction scope like this,

```
using (var scpe=new TransactionScope()){
...
context1.SaveChanges();
....
context.SaveChanges();

scope.Complete();
}
```

> SaveChanges operates within a transaction. SaveChanges will roll back
>   that transaction and throw an exception if any of the dirty
>   ObjectStateEntry objects cannot be persisted.

[See the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336792.aspx)

Comment: (1) Do you mean that DbContext.SaveChanges() inherently implements atomicity without us having to specify explicitly? In which case can we turn it off?

Comment: (2) Also, I didn't quite understand your code for two databases. The Transaction scope seems to be declared as an independent object. How do both context objects know they are within a single scope?

Comment: Actually never mind my second comment. I did not know about .NET ambient transactions and am reading up on them.

Comment: (2) Transaction scope is for distributed transactions. It uses Distributed Transaction Coordinator .